# I have a stack trace and no other information and don't know what is wrong!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hey guys,
i got a problem, with whome i'll likely going to spend the whole night;P So please help me. Here's the error log.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x4b17d10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key linksTableView.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00db1be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f065c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00db1b21 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x000326cf _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 135
    4   Foundation                          0x0003263d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
    5   UIKit                               0x004b18d6 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 112
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00d282cf -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239
    7   UIKit                               0x004b02ed -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
    8   UIKit                               0x004b2081 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    9   UIKit                               0x0036aa94 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70
    10  UIKit                               0x00368709 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    11  UIKit                               0x003685e3 -[UIViewController view] + 56
    12  UIKit                               0x00366a57 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
    13  UIKit                               0x00377201 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
    14  UIKit                               0x00375831 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    15  UIKit                               0x00376b4c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 524
    16  UIKit                               0x00371606 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
    17  UIKit                               0x00489e01 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 226
    18  QuartzCore                          0x01c6f451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    19  QuartzCore                          0x01c6f17c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    20  QuartzCore                          0x01c6837c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    21  QuartzCore                          0x01c680d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    22  QuartzCore                          0x01c987d5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00d92fbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00d280e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf0bd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf0240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf0161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x016e6268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x016e632d GSEventRun + 115
    30  UIKit                               0x002c942e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    31  ORBooks                             0x00001c34 main + 102
    32  ORBooks                             0x00001bc5 start + 53
    33  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Thanks for your time and your knowledge

Comment: Does this help: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=556417 ?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title and more appropriate tags. This is not a "problem with Xcode" since Xcode is the IDE, and the problem is in your own code.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Will do so next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a broken connection to `linksTableView` in Interface Builder. Check the outlets on your view controller.

Comment: @Rew thanks for the link. Helped me figure this out. Thanks for everybody who helped;)